# Seekbar/Seek Buttons are disabled in Exoplayer for .mkv files

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

In an Android App, I am trying to play videos from URL using [Exoplayer](https://exoplayer.dev). For `.mp4` files it plays fine including seeking features. But when I try with `.mkv` videos it plays but seekbar (Timebar) looks like progressbar (doesn't support seeking by user). Also seek buttons do not get activated, nothing happens on click.
Tested with 50+ videos. File size of them are between 20mb to 150mb.

Another confusing observation is everything works with another `.mkv` video with 13 sec duration and size less than 1mb.

Seek feature is not working for large `.mkv` files. Tested with following link *[Link removed after getting solution]*

[image: Seek feature is not working for large mkv files]

Seek feature is working for any `.mp4` files and small `.mkv` files. Works for the following link-
*[Link removed after getting solution]*
[image: Seek feature is working for mp4 files]

Here is my code from android side-

**Dependency-**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.5'
```

**VideoPlayerActivity.java**

```
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)));
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("accept", "application/json");
headers.put(..., ...);
dataSourceFactory.getDefaultRequestProperties().set(headers);

//Also tested with
//DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)));


MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        .createMediaSource(mUri);

player.prepare(videoSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
player.addListener(this);
```

Also tried applying-

```
DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
extractorsFactory.setConstantBitrateSeekingEnabled(true);

MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .setExtractorsFactory(extractorsFactory)
            .createMediaSource(mUri);
```

Is there any option to enable seeking for large `.mkv` video files? Any other libraries will also be appreciated.

**Update**

If I try to seek programmatically with `player.seekTo(15000);` video starts from beginning again.

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: Not yet, just converted all videos to mp4. But any solution still be appreciated.

Comment: can you share your `VideoPlayerActivity`

Comment: The activity contains any other offtopic things. Here are two related methods.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/725nWHRKZm/

Comment: can you add complete code for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that [Exoplayer](https://exoplayer.dev/) works fine with videos codec **H.264** and audio codec **AAC** *(May not be limited to)* (Source: [medium.com](http://ffmpeg%20-i%201593621563_WFKsHQ2vo41sz7ORwf4d8n31o.mp4%20-vcodec%20libx264%20-acodec%20aac%20-crf%2028%20output.mkv)).

I converted my videos using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) with the command below and now mkv files with long duration are working fine for me.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -crf 28 output.mkv
```

`-crf 28` is used to reduce file size keeping the quality almost same.
In my case-

- With `crf` 138M file became 54M in size.
- Without `crf` 138M file became 107M in size.